# what does the logical fallacy "shifting issues" mean?

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of the logical fallacy "shifting issues"? I have tried a web search on many different forms of the question "what is the definition of the logical fallacy shifting issues.  I have tried purdue owl and texts such as The Little Brown Handbook. I cannot find either a definition or synonym for "shifting issues".

Comment: [Logical fallacies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies) - see especially **[Red Herring Fallacies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies#Red_herring_fallacies)**.  Elliott Frisch's answer is probably the intended meaning though.  What is the source for the named logical fallacy (as it seems like less of a logical fallacy and more of a "politician's debating technique")?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a restatement of [Avoiding the Issue](http://www.logicallyfallacious.com/index.php/logical-fallacies/58-avoiding-the-issue)

> **Avoiding the Issue**
>
> shifting attention away from the issue at hand.